# Mapping a domain with a table that doesn't have a primary key

Tags: hibernate, grails, mapping, grails-orm

I'm making a Grails application using GORM and as the title says I've come across a table that doesn't contain a primary key that I need to map in my domain. I know it requires an ID but in this case what can I do to get around it? I've searched and searched but haven't found an answer.

Regards,

Jamie

Comment: In hibernate its not possible to create domain (Table) without primary key

Comment: @Amogh Back to the drawing board then.. thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Amogh Further confirms your point sadly. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should always have a primary key in your table.

If for some reason it's completely impossible to create one, I've seen in the Grails documentation that they allow [composite identifiers](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#compositePrimaryKeys). They don't recommend it, though, and I've never been forced to do it so proceed at your own risk!

Comment: I'll find out if it's a possibility to add a PK to the table on Monday as it's a work related project. Composite ID's wouldn't work in this case unfortunately either.

Comment: Sounds like one jacked up table definitely in need of a PK!

Comment: Ok so I'm trying to use each column (5 of them) to make up a composite key and I'm getting the following error.

Comment: These comment boxes aren't large enough for me to paste the error into? What other option do I have?